# Linux user list & UID / bash layer

Tags: linux, bash, list

Hello I need to Add UID to user list and list only users with bash layer please help

```
Cat /etc/passwd |grep "/etc/passwd" |cut -d: f1
```

Comment: it isn't clear what you're asking here and neither what you're trying to do with your example. At least to me, obv.

Comment: Need to list users from /etc/passwd with UID like: USER1 uid=0001

Comment: See `useradd` or `adduser` commands. `getent passwd | grep /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer

```
grep "/bin/bash" "/etc/passwd" |cut -d\: -f1,3
```

you were so *close*.

Don't underestimate yourself.
If you only would have taken 5 minutes more you would have found it ;-)

Comment: gives permission danied

Comment: Then forget it. If you are not given "read" rights on the passwd file and the system administrator won't give them to you then you are stuck. If you give some more info I might have an idea to work around that drawback but it is not such a solid solution as I gave you here.

Comment: try this and paste me the output: `ls -l /etc/passwd`

Comment: also the output on these: `ls -l $( which grep )` and `ls -l $( which cut )`

Comment: Got it :)

    grep bash /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | while read a; do echo $a `id $a | cut -d '(' -f 1` ; done